# Ubuntu touch app with nodejs library

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, nodejs

I want to write an application with the library in nodejs.
Is there any way to connect QML or C++ with nodejs on ubuntu touch?

Edit: I want to write a native application (in QML) and use a library written in nodejs. How can I call nodejs in QML?

Duplicate question does not respond to the question.

Comment: I don't think this is the right duplicate link. I rather believe, that this is a programming question and belongs on [SO]. Voting to reopen to then close as off topic.